# How to append regex match to a line in vim?

Tags: regex, vim

Is it possible to use `:%s` to find a match somewhere in a line, and then append it to the line?

With following as an example string, I expected something like `:s/\(value\)/\$\1/` to append `value` to the end of the line, but it just adds `$` before `value` inline

Demo string:

```
This value is too damn high!
```

Expected output:

```
This is too damn high!value
```

Actual output:

```
This $value is too damn high!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go fast & dirty:

```
:s,\(.*\)\(value\)\(.*\),\1\3\2,
```

But there are probably cleaner ways to do it.

For find & append (as stated in question):

```
:s,\(.*\(value\).*\),\1\2,
```

Answer (score 2):

In Vim, `\$` is a literal dollar sign. The end-of-line match is simply `$`. You can use `\1` to substitute the first matched group, and `\0` to match the entire match. Hence:

```
:s#.*\(value\).*#\0\1
```

Comment: I don't quite follow what you're doing here, is everything that it's captured automatically put into the `\0` group?

Comment: Yes, `\0` is replaced with the whole matched pattern, whereas `\1` is replaced with first matched *group* (delimited by `\(` and `\)`). I am also using `#` to split up the :s command, but you can use whichever character you wish.